# Capturing a screenshot of a fullscreen game fails

Tags: python, winapi, pywin32, screen-capture, game-automation

This works on a normal window but in a fullscreen game this is returning a black screen so I changed the `dtype = numpy.uint8` to `dtype = numpy.uint16` and now I'm getting the this error. I think it has something to do with the 4 in the tuple.

```
File "C:\Users\phpjunkie\Python\test_debug\testing\test12.py", line 22, in CaptureWwindow
output.shape = (height, width, 4)
^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 12288000 into shape (1600,3840,4)
```

Here is the code:

```py
import phpjunkie.Win32 as Win32
import cv2 as cv
import numpy
import win32gui
import win32ui
import win32con


def CaptureWwindow(hwnd: int):
    left, top, right, bottom = win32gui.GetWindowRect(hwnd)
    width, height = right - left,  bottom - top

    wdc = win32gui.GetWindowDC(hwnd)
    dc = win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle(wdc)
    cdc = dc.CreateCompatibleDC()
    bitmap = win32ui.CreateBitmap()
    bitmap.CreateCompatibleBitmap(dc, width, height)
    cdc.SelectObject(bitmap)
    cdc.BitBlt((0, 0), (width, height), dc, (0, 0), win32con.SRCCOPY)

    output = numpy.frombuffer(bitmap.GetBitmapBits(True), dtype = numpy.uint16)
    output.shape = (height, width, 4)

    dc.DeleteDC()
    cdc.DeleteDC()
    win32gui.ReleaseDC(hwnd, wdc)
    win32gui.DeleteObject(bitmap.GetHandle())

    return output


hwnd = Win32.GetWindowHandle(partial = 'Marvel\'s Spider-Man Remastered')
screenshot = CaptureWwindow(hwnd)
screenshot = (screenshot >> 2).astype(numpy.uint8)

cv.imshow('screenshot', screenshot)
print(screenshot.dtype)
print(screenshot.shape)
cv.waitKey()
```

Comment: If the screenshot is a black screen with `np.uint8`, that implies that every element of the screenshot buffer is zero, and that switching types won't help.

Comment: You can check what percentage of values are zero with the expression `print((output == 0).mean() * 100)`

Comment: don't just try random things and _expect_ them to be sensible ways to a solution. changing the dtype was unlikely to do anything but introduce another issue. the issue is that your chosen method of screen cap can't deal with 3d-accelerated content (the game). find a different method. -- this has nothing to do with opencv or numpy. it's purely winapi.

Comment: You cannot use the GDI to capture screen contents of windows that don't use the GDI to render their contents. Use [`Windows.Graphics.Capture`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.graphics.capture) instead. I don't know whether Python bindings for this namespace exist.

Comment: I know that the fullscreen apps directly render the desktop so the window may not have any content other than black pixels in its device context when it is in fullscreen mode. You should use other capture methods for FA apps by using either IInspectable's suggestion or [Desktop Duplication API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3ddxgi/desktop-dup-api).

Comment: And I was under the impression that programs that use DXGI could protect themselves against copying anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I saw [someone else's code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76373625/pywin32-cannot-capture-certain-windows-giving-black-screen-python-windows/76399855#76399855) and saw three lines that needed to be added that gave me what I wanted and that was to get a screenshot of the game itself and not a screenshot of the desktop.

```py
import cv2 as cv
import numpy
from ctypes import windll # first line
import win32gui
import win32ui
import win32con
from pyvda import AppView, get_apps_by_z_order


def CaptureWwindow(hwnd: int) -> numpy.ndarray:
    if not bool(hwnd):
        return numpy.array([])

    windll.user32.SetProcessDPIAware() # second line

    left, top, right, bottom = win32gui.GetWindowRect(hwnd)
    width, height = right - left, bottom - top

    wdc = win32gui.GetWindowDC(hwnd)
    dc = win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle(wdc)
    cdc = dc.CreateCompatibleDC()
    bitmap = win32ui.CreateBitmap()
    bitmap.CreateCompatibleBitmap(dc, width, height)
    cdc.SelectObject(bitmap)
    cdc.BitBlt((0, 0), (width, height), dc, (0, 0), win32con.SRCCOPY)

    windll.user32.PrintWindow(hwnd, cdc.GetSafeHdc(), 3) # third line

    output = numpy.frombuffer(bitmap.GetBitmapBits(True), dtype = numpy.uint8)
    output.shape = (height, width, 4)

    dc.DeleteDC()
    cdc.DeleteDC()
    win32gui.ReleaseDC(hwnd, wdc)
    win32gui.DeleteObject(bitmap.GetHandle())

    return output


window = [window for window in get_apps_by_z_order(current_desktop = False) if 'Marvel\'s Spider-Man Remastered' in win32gui.GetWindowText(window.hwnd)]
if bool(len(window)):
    window = window[0]

if isinstance(window, AppView):
    screenshot = CaptureWwindow(window.hwnd)
    cv.imshow(winname = 'screenshot', mat = screenshot)
    cv.waitKey()
```

The only problem I found with his code is the `win32gui.GetClientRect(hwnd)` instead of `win32gui.GetWindowRect(hwnd)` was generating all zeros.